# Owasp Zap CSRF token

Tags: owasp

the situation looks as follows,

OWASP ZAP displays the alert "10202 - Absence of Anti-CSRF Tokens".
The scan is done on Joomla! which has a dynamic session-based CSRF implemented.

We can add a custom csrf field in Tools-> Options-> Anti CSRF Tokens, which is a random string and changes per session.

Is it possible to add a token and scan the url addresses that appeared in the alerts again (without having to perform the entire scan again)

Comment: You're not getting a lot of love here.  Perhaps you would like to try [joomla.se] Stack Exchange.